# Anyone know where to get this Windows 7 image file icon?

Tags: windows-7, icons

When I was using windows 7, I set .PNGs to load with Windows Paint instead of the regular photo viewer. And there was this icon the images had that I cannot find in Windows 10.

[icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60J2c.png)

I even went back to an old computer with Windows 7 and was not able to locate where the icon is located.

I used FileTypesMan to load icons from the following programs/locations:
IExplorer.exe
MSpaint (default)
MSPaint XP
System32\Shell32.dll 
System32\AccessibilityCpl.dll
System32\Ddores.dll
System32\GameUx.dll
System32\imageres.dll
System32\MorIcons.dll
System32\mmcndmgr.dll
System32\mmRes.dll
System32\NetCenter.dll
System32\netshell.dll
System32\networkexplorer.dll
System32\PifMgr.dll
System32\PniDui.dll
System32\SensorsCpl.dll
System32\SetupApi.dll
System32\wmploc.dll
System32\wpdshext.dll
System32\DDORes.dll
System32\compstui.dll

Does anyone know any other location where that icon might be located in a Win10 or Win7 machine? I really like this icon and would love to find out where it's located.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a pre-made icon – it's *actually* the mspaint.exe icon overlayed on top of the "blank sheet" icon, which you automatically get whenever you use "Open With" with something that isn't an application already known to Windows.

(For example, opening a .doc with Notepad will usually result in a Notepad-on-a-sheet-of-paper icon. It has worked this way since Windows 95.)

Comment: Additional info: Default mspaint icon is found in `C:\Windows\SystemResources\mspaint.exe.mun` from the icon selection submenus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how do I force this to happen in windows 10?
I've set .PNGs to "Open with" regular MS Paint and Paint XP (the WinXP version of it), and I still don't get the icon the way you explained.